# How can I fix my menu on Android studio its not visible in my activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, menu, android-relativelayout

I have created menu on Res, Directory Res, then menu, inside menu I created dashboard_menu. When I run the menu its not visible. Here is the code on Java.
I tried to change my mini sdk from 23 to 21 as I thought it might be the problem however it didn't change. I want to see the menu on my activity.

`````
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;````
`````

Answer (score 0):

You have created **dashboard_menu** file and you are inflating **R.menu.menu**. Also If you are showing menu icons in Toolbar, then you need to define a Toolbar in the Activity's UI to show these menu items else it doesn't matter what you inflate it won't be visible on screen.

So just define a Toolbar in Activity's UI.

Comment: Thank you,  I managed to fix as per your responses

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code Changed menu -> dashboard_menu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu. dashboard_menu, menu);
   return true;
}
```

Also check activity Theme, make sure to set Toolbar using

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```